# How to test a GraphQL query if its fragment is defined?

Tags: graphql

I have compound fragments:

```
const FragmentA = `fragment FragmentA {
  b {
    ...FragmentB
  }
}
`
const FragmentB = `fragment FragmentB {
  field
  field1
  field2
}
`

const Fragments = `
  ${FragmentA}
  ${FragmentB}
`
```

Is there a way to unit-test, if this `FragmentB` was added to `Fragments` and if the whole `Fragments` is valid?

Comment: Can you expand a bit? 
What do you mean `was added` to Fragments? If you want to check the response that came after request, you can do it just by checking fields on your data.

Comment: **you can do it just by checking fields on your data**

in this case, I have to make an actual request, right? instead I want to just validate if I miss some fragments. anyway, I found some way [here](https://github.com/graphql/graphql-js/blob/master/src/__tests__/starWarsValidation-test.js)